# How to remotely use Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am building a project using Bootstrap 4, which is still in development.
Compiling etc is over my head.
What is the best way to use the required Bootstrap 4 files on official servers?

ie. one option is https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css
another is https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

(I have tried both options, but am seeing old-fashioned gradient-style buttons, not new, flat ones).

What are the merits of each?
And what other files do I need to add?
ie.

```
<!-- JavaScript: placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">           
</script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Uraz, thank-you. Even with these files included instead, I cannot fathom why I am still seeing old-type buttons with a gradient http://imgur.com/emMFaHr

Comment: its working for me perfectly I dont know whats wrong with your code. Instead of sending the pic can u please provide me some code that you have done.